# create a regex pattern

Tags: regex

I want to create a pattern for my string: It should follow this rules:
1th place contains only 4 digits.
2th place contains only one '-'.
3th place contains only 3 digits.
4th place contains only one '-'.
5th place contains only 3 digits.
6th place contains only 6 digits.
7th place contains only one '-'.
8th place contains only 1 digit.

sth like this: `0010-155-072-120410-0`

I use this but not work: `'/[1-9]{4}-[1-9]{3}-[1-9]d{3}-[1-9]{6}-[1-9]{1}/'`

Comment: You are basically correct. Your mistake is that you should type `[0-9]` to include the digit 0, and you should also remove the `d`

Comment: Please mention the language you're using. There are many different varieties of regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'/^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{6}-\d$/'
```

Use this. In your example you have extra `"d"` character at the middle.
Also don't forget to include start and end symbols to avoid extra characters at begining and at the end.

Comment: Why do you keep the `{1}` bit?